# Prototype function linked to button not working

Tags: javascript, oop

I have a class (I think this is called) and created an object called `peter` in my code. I now want to level up `Peter` as follows:

```
// Define the class
function character(name, level){
   this.name = name;
   this.level = level;
}

// Create Peter at level 1
var peter = new character("Peter", 1);

// This will display the name of the character, level and a button to level him up
character.prototype.display = function() {
    document.getElementById("name").innerHTML += this.name;
    document.getElementById("level").innerHTML += this.level;

    // This line calls `levelup()` on load which is not what I want
    // and clicking the button no more calls `levelup`!
    document.getElementById("levelupbutton").onclick = this.levelup();

    // This line would call the function on click, but it looks like `this`
    // is not being passed down to the function `levelup` so I get NaN on
    // this.level down below?
    //document.getElementById("levelupbutton").onclick = this.levelup;
};


character.prototype.levelup = function() {
    alert("Level up in progress!");
    this.level++;
    alert(this.level);
}

peter.display();
```

[jsfilldle](http://jsfiddle.net/sjfxorxz/1/)

I'm probably incorrectly calling the function and I can't seem to figure out how to do it correctly. Can anyone give me some pointers? I'm new to OOP, so if the solution involves something OOP, could you please try to explain it as much as possible?

Comment: `.onclick = this.levelup();` will call the function and assign the returned value as the callback function. You need to use it as `.onclick = this.levelup;`. Notice removed braces, this will assign the reference of the function to onclick, and the function will be called when the click event occurs.

Comment: @Tushar Please read the question. I tried both with and without and have described the (unwanted) behaviours.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to `bind` this to `levelup` and not call it in line to get your desired behavior. [Updated your fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sjfxorxz/4/) with the correct answer.

```js
levelupbutton.onclick = this.levelup.bind(this);
```

```js
function character(name, level){
  this.name = name;
  this.level = level;
}
var peter = new character("Peter", 1); // Instantiate new objects with 'new'
character.prototype.display = function(){
  document.getElementById("name").innerHTML += this.name;
  document.getElementById("level").innerHTML += this.level;
  document.getElementById("levelupbutton").onclick = this.levelup.bind(this);
};
character.prototype.levelup = function(){
  alert("Level up in progress!");
  this.level++;
  alert(this.level);
}
peter.display();
```

```html
<span>Character Name:</span> <span id="name"></span><br />
<span>Character Level:</span> <span id="level"></span><br />
<button id="levelupbutton">Level Up!</button>
```

Comment: Thank you, this looks like what I was looking for, and it actually looks pretty simple. Admittedly though, I would have never found that one out.

Comment: You should look into JavaScript: The Good Parts by Douglas Crockford.  It'll help you gain some awareness of the power of JavaScript.

Answer (score 2):

When attaching a handler function to an element, the value of this inside of the handler is a reference to the element. It is the same as the value of the `e.target` property of the event argument that is passed to the handler.

Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener#The_value_of_this_within_the_handler

You could use [`Function.prototype.bind()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) method which will create a new function that will have its `this` set to the provided value.

Just attach the `click` handler like this:

```
document.getElementById("levelupbutton").addEventListener('click', 
    this.levelup.bind(this)
);
```

[Why use addEventListener?](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener#Why_use_addEventListener)

> `addEventListener` is the way to register an event listener as
>   specified in W3C DOM..

**Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/sjfxorxz/6/**

**Snippet:**

```js
function character(name, level) {
    this.name = name;
    this.level = level;
}
character.prototype.levelup = function() {
    this.level++; 
    document.getElementById("level").innerHTML += this.level;
}
character.prototype.display = function() {
    document.getElementById("name").innerHTML += this.name;
    document.getElementById("level").innerHTML += this.level;
    document.getElementById("levelupbutton").addEventListener('click', 
  this.levelup.bind(this)
 );
}

var peter = new character("Peter", 1);
peter.display();
```

```html
<span>Character Name:</span> <span id="name"></span><br />
<span>Character Level:</span> <span id="level"></span><br />
<button id="levelupbutton">Level Up!</button>
```

---

Alternatively, you could also save the reference and use that inside an anonymous function call instead of inlining it.

*For example:*

```
character.prototype.display = function() {
    var self = this;
    document.getElementById("levelupbutton").addEventListener('click', 
        function () {
            self.levelup();
    });
}
```

**Fiddle 2: http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/sjfxorxz/9/**

**Snippet 2:**

```js
function character(name, level) {
    this.name = name;
    this.level = level;
}
character.prototype.levelup = function() {
    this.level++; 
    document.getElementById("level").innerHTML += this.level;
}
character.prototype.display = function() {
    var self = this;
    document.getElementById("name").innerHTML += this.name;
    document.getElementById("level").innerHTML += this.level;
    document.getElementById("levelupbutton").addEventListener('click', 
  function () {
         self.levelup();
    });
}

var peter = new character("Peter", 1);
peter.display();
```

```html
<span>Character Name:</span> <span id="name"></span><br />
<span>Character Level:</span> <span id="level"></span><br />
<button id="levelupbutton">Level Up!</button>
```

Comment: Ok, could you tell me the advantage(s) of using your solution as opposed to Isaac's?

Comment: @Jerry: Pertaining to the `this` reference, it is the same (*he beat me to it by a couple of minutes while I was still typing out my answer*). The only difference is the use of `addEventListener`. This has two advantages: one, it allows adding more than a single handler for an event and two, its third parameter allows to capture event bubbling. Not that it matters for your use-case of the question. Both inline handler and event listener will get the job done in this case.

Comment: Thank you so much @Jerry. It was unexpected and took me by surprise!

Comment: No problem Abhitalks. I did not end up using your solution, but your answer provided good insight (might be using that solution in a different situation!), and I appreciated your quick replies to my queries. Such a detailed and elaborate answer deserves it :)